# Problem with post request in RESTful api in codeigniter and ionic app

Tags: php, apache, rest, codeigniter, http

I have api that created by REST_Controller in my codeigniter project and we have ionic app that connect to api with angular. when app send get request, api works properly. but when app send post request, we have 405 error (405 Method Not Allowed).

this is my error :

https://cdn1.imggmi.com/uploads/2019/9/17/082f799c503bb5ea405a88e0759aaa0b-full.jpg

this is my controller :

I am try config php header but api dont work.

```
use Restserver\Libraries\REST_Controller;
require(APPPATH.'/libraries/REST_Controller.php');
require(APPPATH.'/libraries/REST_Controller_Definitions.php');
require(APPPATH.'/libraries/Format.php');


class Mobile_api extends REST_Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {   
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('Flights_model');
    }


    public function search_post(){

        $from = $this->post('from');
        $to = $this->post('to');
        $date = $this->post('date');
        $adult = $this->post('adult');
        $child = $this->post('child');
        $infant = $this->post('infant');
        $type = $this->post('type');

        if(!$from || !$to || !$date || !$adult || !$type){

                $this->response("Enter complete search information", 400);

        }else{
            $this->session->set_userdata("adult", $adult);
            $this->session->set_userdata("child", $child);
            $this->session->set_userdata("infant", $infant);
            $token = rand(1000,9999).time();
            $result = array();
            $counter = 0;

            $result = $this->Flights_model->get_result($from, $to, $date, $token, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);

            if($result){

                $this->response($result, 200); 

                exit;
            } 
            else{

                 $this->response("Invalid ISBN", 404);

                exit;
            }
        }
    }



}
```

Comment: Don't link to an image of an error message. **Edit your question** to add your error message as *text*.

Comment: this is error :    Request Methode: OPTIONS , Status Code :  405 Method Not Allowed